# EAGLE Library sub directory

Tags: eaglecad, library

How can I keep multiple libraries of a similar type grouped, say multiple terminal blocks with a different number of pins. I want to have a drop down menu that says "Terminal_Blocks" with several different sizes under that.

Something like this:

Terminal_Blocks

T_BLK_3

Symbol      Package

T_BLK_6

Symbol      Package

T_BLK_10

Symbol      Package

I can't use variant since they don't share the same symbol but I still want them grouped since they are all terminal blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the multiple T_BLK_*n* devices in the same library.  You don't need a dropdown.  These devices with the same leading characters of their names will be grouped together anyway.  You can also type "T" to get to the first devices that start with T, then down arrow from there.  It's really not hard, and generally easier than lots of clickety-clicking anyway.